# How to count data group by per 6 hours interval in every day in timestamp from database in PHP?

Tags: php

this is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE( pm_timestamp ) AS d, HOUR( pm_timestamp ) AS h, 
       COUNT( * ) AS c FROM pm_impr_tracker WHERE campaign_id = '$camp_id' GROUP BY h,d order by `pm_timestamp`";
```

this gives per hours data but i want per 6 hours.
my results:

```
    d       h   c
2015-08-23  6   6
2015-08-23  7   11
2015-08-23  8   26 
2015-08-23  9   57
2015-08-23  10  36
2015-08-23  11  19
2015-08-23  12  21
2015-08-23  13  18
2015-08-23  14  18
2015-08-23  15  17
2015-08-23  16  107
2015-08-23  17  55
2015-08-24  8   26
2015-08-24  9   57
2015-08-24  10  36
2015-08-24  11  19
2015-08-24  12  21
2015-08-24  13  18
2015-08-24  14  18
```

Comment: I'd recommend writing a Stored Procedure for this and only pass the parameters, but this depends on your DB, of course.

Comment: Is `$camp_id` sourced from user input? If so, be careful about SQL injection here. Consider using parameter binding if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted groups the records by hour. If you need them grouped by intervals of 6 hours then all you have to do is to make `h` be the number of such a 6 hours group in the day. For example, `h = 0` is the group of hours `0..5` (i.e. HOUR(`pm_timestamp`) between 0 and 5), `h = 1` is for hours `6..11` and so on.

This can be easily achieved if you divide the hour by 6 and ignore the remainder. That's what the MySQL [`DIV operator`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_div) does for a living.

The query is:

```
SELECT DATE(pm_timestamp) AS d,
    HOUR(pm_timestamp) DIV 6 AS h, 
    COUNT(*) AS c
FROM pm_impr_tracker
WHERE campaign_id = '$camp_id'
GROUP BY h, d
```